# Identity and classify Similar Strings in observations under same variable

Tags: r, string, dplyr, string-matching

[This is the dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/eliasdabbas/boxofficemojo-alltime-domestic-data) that I'm working with. I'm trying to write a query/function that would go through column `title` and identify originals and sequels based on string similarity. I want it to pick up similarities in character, and being able to distinguish between, e.g., `Transformers` and `Transformers: Age of Extinction`. I'm thinking using `year` to help R identify which ones are originals, and which ones are sequels.

If possible, this is the result that I"m looking for:

```
Title      | Lifetime_Gross | Year   | Kind
Toy Story  | $$$            | 1995   | Original
Toy Story 2| $$$            | 1999   | Sequel
Transformers| $$$           | 2007   | Original
Transformers2 | $$$         | 2009   | Sequel
and so on.
```

Comment: Why not arrange by title and year? With `library(dplyr)` `my_data %>% arrange(Title, Year) %>% group_by(Title, Year) %>% mutate(count = 1:n()) `

Comment: Then you should have `count == 1` for the "Originals", all the others will be "Sequels".

Comment: @RLave that will work as long as the sequels begin with the same words but will fail for cases like "Return of the Mummy" - just a sample sequel for The mummy.

Comment: Agreed, but the year would be different? Maybe it's just sufficient to arrange and group just by year.

Comment: @RLave, didn't work with count, because down the column everything is count = 1

Comment: Please post the code you used.